# Cannot push new flow version or update current version

Tags: metadata-api, visual-workflow

I am using egit with eclipse, using metadata api I refreshed the flow folder in force.com ide where I was able to see new version of flow that was created.

[image]

In the this environment, where I edited version 2, I could see all the changes I made. Then I tried two things I copied and pasted `Create_Activities_for_Project_Management_Guide_2.flow` over into the dev branch, committed and pushed, then merged successfully. Deployment status was successfull; but this version never showed up?:

[image]

... according to [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_visual_workflow.htm) document you can update an active flow. So I copied the contents of version 2 over to version 1, commited and pushed, then merged, deployement was successful but the changes did not appear?

I wonder because at the top of version 2 it still says:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Flow xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
```

.. any ideas ?

also there are no active or paused interviews.

Found in package.xml that the `<name>Flow</name>` was commented out, so I uncommented and specified my flows, then when deploying I get:

```
Create_Activities_for_Project_Management_Guide-2.flow An object 'Create_Activities_for_Project_Management_Guide-2.flow' of type Flow was named in package.xml, but was not found in zipped directory
Create_Activities_for_Project_Management_Guide-1.flow An object 'Create_Activities_for_Project_Management_Guide-1.flow' of type Flow was named in package.xml, but was not found in zipped directory
```

Comment: did you also push the FlowDefinition resource?

Comment: No, see my update

Comment: could that be cause by no FlowDefinition ?

Comment: FlowDefinition defines which of the Flow is active

Comment: Ah, well the problem is that the flow isn't showing up at all and no changes to the active one are showing